# How to download a file from an SFTP server using Node

Tags: node.js, download, sftp

I'm looking to let a user download a file directly from an sftp server, but in the browser. For example, user wants to find a audio file name called 'noise', they enter the parameters and a button shows to download. I am using express as my web application framework and as well as ejs.

I've found methods to download via SFTP like the code below but this is saved through my applications folder rather than the user's disk.

```
        sftp.connect(config).then(() => {  
            sftp.get('file.wav').then((data) => {
              var outFile = fs.createWriteStream('file.wav')
              data.on('data',function(response) {
                outFile.write(response);
              });
              data.on('close', function() {
                outFile.close();
              });
            });
        })
```

How can you download directly from sftp to the user's disk by giving them the option through a button?

Comment: You didn't specify how your http is setup.  Are you using express?

Comment: Yes I am, sorry about that.

Comment: How you finally solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You pipe the stream to your `res`.  For example:

```
router.get('/download', (req, res) => {
   sftp.connect(config).then(() => {  
      sftp.get('file.wav').then((data) => {
        res.pipe(data)
      })
   })
})
```

Comment: I called this route like `<a href="/download" download> Download file</a>`. Once I clicked the href, it just gave me a load request with nothing coming up. Do you klnow what a possible issue could be?